# Check if uitableviewcell is 30% visible when going offscreen while User scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there any way while the user is scrolling an uitableview to know when one of the many uitableviewcells is offscreen by 70% when reaching the top? Should i use willdisplaycell for this? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Implement `scrollViewDidScroll`...

- get the frame of the row / cell you want to track
- compare it to the scroll offset to see how much of it is visible

In this simple example, `rowToTrack` is an `NSInteger`, such as `2` for the 3rd row, `sectionToTrack` is an `NSInteger`, such as `0` for the 1st section:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    
    // index path for row we want to track
    NSIndexPath *p = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowToTrack inSection:sectionToTrack];
    
    // get frame for that row
    CGRect r = [self.tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:p];
    
    // get bottom of row frame
    CGFloat t1 = CGRectGetMaxY(r);
    
    // get scroll content offset
    CGFloat t2 = scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.adjustedContentInset.top;
    
    // height of visible portion of row frame
    CGFloat visibleHeight = t1 - t2;
    
    // as a percentage between 0 and 1
    CGFloat pct = MAX(0.0, MIN(1.0, visibleHeight / r.size.height));

    NSLog(@"Row %ld is %0.2f percent visible", rowToTrack, pct * 100);
    
}
```